# How can I check if an attribute of a class exists in array?

Tags: python, arrays

I want to know if it is possible to check if an array of a class has a specific instance of an attribute, and return True if it does. In other words, does an instance of a class attribute exist in an array of that class?

In my example, I have an array of class `Team`. The class `Team` has an attribute, `name`. I want to check if a `Team` instance with a specific `name` exists by iterating over an array of `Team` instances.

**Class Team:**

```
class Team:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = name  # (String)
```

[Invalid] This is the how I wanted to write the function:

```
# team_name is a String variable
# teams is an array of the Team class

def team_name_taken(team_name, teams):
    if team_name in teams.name:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

I know this doesn't work, but is it possible to iterate over the same attribute within an array in this fashion?

[Valid] Regarding the goal of my code, I have the following code that works properly:

```
def team_name_taken(team_name, teams):
    for team in teams:
        if team_name == team.name:
            return True
    return False
```

I know that this works, I was just wondering if there was another way to do it, similar to the invalid way I represented above.

Comment: You cannot do `teams.name` as `teams` is not of the class `Team`. So, I would say what you have working is correct/more adequate.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, and I understood why it didn't work, it was more so the general approach I was curious about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is the following:

```
def team_name_taken(team_name, teams):
    team_names = [team.name for team in teams]
    if team_name in team_names:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

This will generate a list with the items of the list being all team names. Once you have done that you can do `if team_name in team_names:` and get the desired outcome.

If on the other hand you just want to make it a oneliner you could do this:

```
def team_name_taken(team_name, teams):
    return len([ team for team in teams if team.name == team_name ]) >= 1
```

This will make a `list` then check if the `len()` of the list is 1 (or bigger) and if that is the case return `True` else `False`.

Answer (score 0):

The following class definition allows `name` from the user to be assigned to the `Team.name` attribute and forces it to be a `str` object:

```
class Team(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = str(name)
```

Here is an example list of `Team` instances:

```
teams = [Team(x) for x in range(10)]
```

You can do what I think you want with some one-liners:

Using another list comprehension to find out if any of the `name`s equal `'3'`:

```
any([team.name == '3' for team in teams])
```

Or if you really want to use a function you can use the following:

```
any(map(lambda obj: obj.name == '3', teams))
```